# Magento faceted search only shows filters of current page

Tags: search, magento, solr

We are using SOLR as our search engine. When I search for a product, say "computer", the filters on the left side only shows the filters for the results of the current page.

Suppose I have 35 IBM computers and 15 TULIP, my page would display only 10 products per page. I would have 5 pages then. The first two pages, maybe only have IBM computers, then IBM and Tulip, and then only Tulip.

The thing is, when I am on page 1, the filter "Brand" on the left side only shows the option to filter by "IBM", because that's the only brand on the page.

How can I make sure that the brand from *all* the search results are used to display the brand filters.

Comment: Ok, I got a little further. We have two store views: business and customers. It seems that the business view is working okay, the other view isn't.

I can see that two different queries are coming into SOLR. How can it be possible that the query made to SOLR depends on the store view?

A little further, a little more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was a function getIsEngineAvailableForNavigation() which can be found in /app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Helper/Data.php.

The price tax check was causing our problems.